# JAX-RS: is @DefaultValue passed even if some incorrect data type is passed?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

My endpoint looks like

```
 @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getVariables(@QueryParam("_activeonly") @DefaultValue("no") @Nonnull final Active active) {
        switch (active) {
            case yes:
                return Response.ok(VariablePresentation.getPresentationVariables(variableManager.getActiveVariables())).build();
            case no:
                return Response.ok(VariablePresentation.getPresentationVariables(variableManager.getVariables())).build();
        }
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Where `Active` is

```
  public enum Active {
        yes,
        no;
    }
```

and I test it as

```
   @Test
    public void testGetAllVariablesUnknownActionFail() throws Exception {
        final ClientRequest clientRequest = new ClientRequest("http://localhost:9090/market/rest/variables?_activeonly=unknown");
        final ClientResponse<String> clientResponse = clientRequest.get(String.class);
        assertEquals(400, clientResponse.getStatus());
    }
```

While I expect `HTTP 400`, I receive `HTTP 200`

```
: expected:<400> but was:<200>
```

Does that mean if I passed in some incorrect value, which is not mapped to enum, `@DefaultValue` is used?

Comment: I'd put in a breakpoint or print an out the active variable inside the endpoint and see what you get. I would have expected an issue with the serialization.